# MySQL float type range and precision confusion

Tags: mysql, floating-point

I'm learning MySQL and having problem with `float`'s range and precision.

From the [mannual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html):

> For FLOAT, the SQL standard permits an optional specification of the precision (but not the range of the exponent) in bits following the keyword FLOAT in parentheses. MySQL also supports this optional precision specification, but the precision value is used only to determine storage size. A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.

I created a table using this command

```
create table test (f_a float(23));
```

I'm having 4 confusions:

1. what's the meaning of `but not the range of the exponent` in the mannual?
2. I can execute `insert into test values (1e38);` without problems. Even if I type `38` digits it still works. But `39` digits or `1e39` will fail. So what's the meaning of this `38`?
3. How can I inspect the type conversion of `f_a`? When I execute `desc test;` the type of `f_a` is still `float` even after I inserted a `38` digits number into that column.
4. So, what's the difference between **range** and **precision** on earth?

Comment: Excellent answer below, but also good advice is *don't use these data types* unless you have a specific, informed reason for doing so -- these types store *approximate* values, and favor range over precision.  Using `DECIMAL` is usually what you want. Floats and doubles are necessarily imprecise.  If you are calculating money, the `DECIMAL` data type is the only acceptable type.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Good point! Many tks Mr. Bot:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEEE floating point representation isn't unique to MySQL. It follows the same standard used everywhere.

1) disregard the length specifier, That's just noise. In MySQL, there are exactly *two* floating point datatypes: single precision (32-bits) and double precision (64-bits.)

That optional length specifier is just provides an alternate way to specify `DOUBLE`.

```
 alter table t add foo FLOAT(4), add bar FLOAT(40) ;
```

is equivalent to

```
 alter table t add foo FLOAT  , add bar DOUBLE ;
```

2) The 38 in  `1e38`  is the exponent power of 10. That's equivalent to

```
1.0 x 10^38
```

Without diving into all of the details, a floating point number is essentially expressed as

```
   sign * mantissa  * (radix ^ exponent)
```

For example, in base10, we could express the value `123.45` in this way:

```
    +1  * 0.12345   * ( 10 ^ 3 )
```

Or, we could use base2, and express a value (between 0 and 1) times some power of 2.

3)  `1e39` (1.0*10^39) is larger than the range of values that can be expressed in IEEE single precision FLOAT. ("The maximum representable IEEE 754 floating-point value is 2 * 2^−23 * 2^27  which is approximately 3.402x10^38.

A DOUBLE precision floating point supports a much larger range of values, up to 10^308.

4) **range** is the smallest value to the largest value.  For DOUBLE, the range is from `-1 * 10^308`  to `10^308`.

**precision** is basically the number of *digits* that can be represented.  For a single precision FLOAT, we get approximately 7 decimal digits of precision. For a DOUBLE, we a precision in the neighborhood of twice that, 15 decimal digits.

--

The IEEE floating point isn't unique to MySQL. Nearly all modern processors include floating point arithmetic units, that operate on floating point numbers.

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: tks so much for your effort!